# Regex is not matching - Firestore

Tags: firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm checking if any of the user's roles are part of a document's allowed roles. The following should match since the user is an admin+**editor**, and the post allows reading by publisher+**editor**:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /group/{groupId} {
        match /posts/{postId} {
        allow read: if 'admin,editor'.matches('((,|^)(publisher|editor)(,|$))');
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Here's it working in a regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/bDXMg3/2/

But this fails to match, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Our docs could be clearer on this, but it looks like the whole string needs to match. Give `(.*,|^)(publisher|editor)(,.*|$)` a try.